# how to print total number of posts filtered by category?

Tags: posts, categories

I want to print total number of posts filtered by its category. for example if there are 3 posts in category "abc" and 5 posts in category "xyz". when i am in any post of category "abc" then it should display 3 and if i am in any post of category "xyz" then it should print 5.
Thanks

with this piece of code i am struggling to acheive these functionality

```
foreach((get_the_terms($post->ID, 'project_category')) as $term) { 
echo $term->term_id. ''; 
}
```

above code will result the term id of current category. suppose the result is 7 then we put it in this code

```
$term = get_term( '7', 'category' ); 
$count = $term->count;
echo $count;
```

this will result total number of posts in current category . Now instead of hard coding '7' how can we achieve the result dynamically ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count how many posts in category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20973/count-how-many-posts-in-category-based-on-result-display-link-or-not)

Comment: its not duplicate

Comment: Why not? Aren't you asking how to count how many posts are in one category?

Comment: What code did you use and where did you put it @MuhammadOmarFarooq

Comment: You should really edit your post to include the code from your comments in a code block so we can actually read it.

Comment: Someone should post this code as an answer with an explanation on how it works.

Comment: I've add the code (hours ago) to the question but for whatever reason the mods didn't accept/like it?!

Comment: i have added the code in question

Comment: You want to get the count of the total posts in a `taxonomy` or for each `term` of that `taxonomy` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do

```
foreach((get_the_terms($post->ID, 'project_category')) as $term) { 
   echo $term->term_id, " -> ", $term->count,  '<br>';
   // if post assigned to more than once category you will have multiple lines 
}
```

Basically `get_the_terms` call already returns `term` object, so you can access all properties, including `count`

Comment: that works perfectly