# Why get_category() function is not working not working when embedded in a page?

Tags: categories

I'm using PHP everywhere plugin to insert PHP snippets in my page. Specifically, I'm trying to get posts count in a category. Here's my code:

```
<?php  
$count=get_category(607)->count;
echo $count;
?>
```

But it doesn't display any value, and there is no way of checking what it is returning. The plugin works fine. For example, if I enter `echo 1+1` 
it displays 2.
Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This answer [Count how many posts in category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20973/count-how-many-posts-in-category) says to use this code

```
$category = get_category($id);
$count = $category->category_count;
```

Comment: Thank you I have used that too but the same result.

Comment: If the ID of the category is '640', then the get_category('640') should get you an array of items belonging to that category. Try a print_r of $category (just after the first line in my example) and see the array values returned.